# Android detecting real recording, MediaRecorder has delay

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I would like to synchronize data from phone with elapsed time recording video. I would like to get information (in ms) about elapsed time recording video. I tried resolve it via:
1. Run myself timing.
Pseudo:

```
mMediaRecorder.start(); //start recording
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //save start recording time
timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0); //for save elapsed time and timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 20); for next 20ms
```

but there is problem with MediaRecorder, because real recording not starts after MediaRecorder.start() immediately, but real video recording have different delay (depends on device, ...). I need "some"  callback or catch event when MediaRecorder really start recording.

[image] 
Information about stop recording is not need it, because i can check real video duration via:

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(storage.getVideoFile());
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(stream.getFD());
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
```

I tried get actual duration via MediaMetadataRetriever while recording, but it works only on closed video file.

I tried to detect via FileObserver and onEvent, but it is accurate.

If it possible, i would like to solve via Android SDK. But how?
[min SDK:  API21]

Thank you.

Comment: Starting the timer immediately after mp.start() returns isn't good enough?

Comment: I am trying to solve recording, not playing. When you mean MediaRecorder.start(), no, because between MediaRecorder.start() and real recording is on my device ~700ms.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I know that probably you solved this problem after these 7 months but... 
By looking at the picture you posted you can compute the REAL VIDEO LENGTH with MediaMetadataRetriever an then, by defining `"a"` as the elapsed time from
`Mediarecorder.start()` to the first acquired frame and `"b"` the elapsed time from the last acquired frame to `Mediarecorder.stop()` and assuming that a=b you can compute the start recording instant by:

`startTime + a`

where:

```
a = b = ((stopTime - startTime) - REAL VIDEO LENGTH)/2

startTime = System.nanoTime() (called right after MediaRecorder.start())

stopTime = System.nanoTime() (called right after MediaRecorder.stop())
```

Comment: Thank you. "... and assuming that a=b you can compute the start recording instant by ..." But a != b.

Comment: Did you find another solution?

Comment: I just tested this approach on a few different android phone and it appears to give a very close approximation.